# MS SQL show percent extents changed per table

Tags: sql-server, backup, disk-space, sql-server-2022

I've got differential backups set up for MS SQL Server 2022 and would like to know how much each table in the database is contributing towards the size of the differential backup.

The page below shows how to get the info at the database level, but I'd like to see the % changed extents since last full backup on a per table level.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5688/script-to-show-how-much-a-sql-server-database-has-changed-since-last-full-backup/

Is there a way to do this?

---

I would like to know what tables are getting updated and how many bytes they are contributing to the differential backup. Of course, the number will grow over time until a new full backup is taken.

Comment: A related question might be how much each table is contributing to the size of a Transaction Log backup.
https://michaeljswart.com/2020/01/what-tables-are-being-written-to-the-most/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't track that directly, but you've got a couple options.

**Option 1, painful and inaccurate:** Start with the DBCC page technique in [the post you linked to](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5688/script-to-show-how-much-a-sql-server-database-has-changed-since-last-full-backup/), but for every page that you examine, you'll also need to look at the DBCC PAGE contents to see which objectid it belongs to by joining to sys.all_objects. It's going to be painful to write, and it's also going to take quite some time in order to run. Even worse, it won't be accurate because as your query is running, the pages could actually be switched over to different objects. For example, if a table got dropped, some of the pages could get newly allocated to some other object, and your tracking would report the "wrong" object as contributing to the differential.

**Option 2, fast and inaccurate:** use the index DMVs to track which objects are getting the most writes. My personal favorite way to do this is the open source [sp_BlitzIndex](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/). Run this:

```
EXECUTE sp_BlitzIndex
    @GetAllDatabases = 1, 
    @Mode = 2, 
    @SortOrder = 'writes', 
    @SortDirection = 'DESC'; -- (set by default)
```

That'll give you which indexes are getting the most writes (changing the most). However, that's not necessarily exactly what's contributing to differential backup size either, because:

- It won't show objects that are getting created, then dropped
- If the same row is getting repeatedly updated, it'll look like high writes when it's only changing one page

I'd still start with that option because it'll give you a rough idea, quickly, and it sounds like that's all you're after. (It doesn't sound like you want to write the query in Option 1, and I'm certainly not doing that for you for free, ha ha ho ho.)

Comment: wow, sp_BlitzIndex is juicy.  I had to @BringThePain=1.  i'm not sure i'm getting what i need (i have a CCI that I added 3,000,000 rows to and is only showing 10 writes) but it's definitely going to keep me busy for a while fixing stuff.  thanks!

Comment: @CoderBrien the writes number reflects the number of times the index was written to, but not the number of rows. If you do a single insert statement that pulls a million rows from another table, that’ll only show 1 write.